# Meaning of "moving right along"

Tags: slang

What does the slang *moving right along* mean?

Comment: I'm not sure it's slang, more of a figure of speech. Nobody is moving, but the metaphor is that the conversation is standing still and should quickly advance to the next topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means "enough of that topic, let's go to the next topic since we are under time constraints"...

Comment: It can be shortened to "Anyhoo..."

Comment: Additionally, this phrase can be used sarcastically when the speaker is eager to leave a particularly awkward topic of conversation.

Answer (score 6):

It also means "making good progress," in reference to a lengthy project, like constructing a building, writing a book, planning a wedding, etc.

Comment: I'd use *moving along* for that purpose. *Moving right along* is a phase I associate with upper- or middle-class English comedies. It is used when whatever is happening is embarrassing and the speaker wants to talk about something else.

Comment: Interesting. Being English, I'd always assumed *moving right along* to be American.

Comment: @TimLymington - I agree, I think that the English version is "moving swiftly along" - it's used in exactly the same context though.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to say "moving along" it would mean making progress along some course of action. For example, "My painting is moving along," means that the painting I am working on is getting closer to completion.

If you change that to "moving right along" it means that you are making progress without any setbacks or interruptions. As [Geoffrey Pullum](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/11/13/thats-right/) describes it, you can use right as an adverb when there is a proper, perfect way to execute a verb. You can move right along, but you can't wander right around.

> The way correctness links to the special preposition-modifying use of right, then, is that there can be an absolutely right way to instantiate a spatial or temporal relation (or metaphorical analog thereof). Right lays emphasis on the instantiation being exactly the right one for the job.